# What do gleemen do that Thom says "why, I'd double his custom just by sitting here."?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

In the novel, *The Eye of the World*, the first in the saga *The Wheel of Time* by Robert Jordan,  Rand's little troupe, after meeting the Travellers, find themselves at an inn, where they have the following exchange:

> The inn-keeper nodded to the low wall. "The other sides that's as best    I've got unless you want to take a room. For when sailors come up from the river. Seems like half the crew's got grudges against the other half. I won't have my place broke up by fights, so I keep them apart." He had been eyeing Thom's cloak the whole while, and now he cocked his head to one side, a sly look in his eyes. "You staying? Haven't had a gleeman here in some time. Folks would pay real good for something as would take  their minds off things. I'd even take some off your room and meals."
>
> Unnoticed, Rand thought glumly.
>
> "You are too generous," Thom said with a smooth bow. "Perhaps I will take up your offer. But for now, a little privacy."
>
> ...
>
> Thom ... [says]  "did you hear that fellow? He'll take some off. Why, I'd double his custom just by sitting here. Any honest inn-keeper gives a gleeman room and board and a good bit besides."

What do gleemen do that Thom says such a thing?

Comment: Despite believing that you probably have a good idea of this considering that it was mentioned various times up to that point, I will point out that gleemen tell stories and entertain. They are bards or minstrels. This could bring more customers to an inn or public house. "Double custom" = "double the customer base."

Comment: Why are you putting "novel" and "saga" in scare quotes? Do you not believe that it is a novel?

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR:** Gleemen are **entertainers**, and people will either come to the inn just to see them perform, or at least stay there longer than they would have otherwise.

We see this many times later in the series, notably just a few chapters later when Rand and Mat are travelling through Andor towards Caemlyn by themselves, especially chapters 31 and 32. They don't have much money to buy food and lodgings for themselves, but they have Thom's flute and juggling balls and what little he's taught them of his skills. They're far from professional gleemen, but they're skilled enough that innkeepers will give them free food and beds in return for their entertainment.

People want entertainment. In the pre-industrial setting of high fantasy such as the *Wheel of Time* series, with no television and not many books, entertainment would often mean travelling singers or storytellers. This was also true in the real world some centuries ago, with [minstrels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minstrel) and [bards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bard) forming an important part of medieval European culture, and a solid [bardic tradition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_bardic_poetry) in some cultures such as Celtic.

If an inn has no entertainment, people will come to eat and drink, and then take their leave or go to their rooms. With the addition of even mediocre entertainers like Rand and Mat with their juggling and music, they'll be more inclined to stay for another drink and another song. With a professional gleeman like Thom, people might come just to hear his stories, even if they weren't already there. More custom means more money for the innkeeper, therefore they are (or should be) willing to help out a gleeman in exchange for him being there.

Comment: In addition, Thom has a very high opinion about himself, bit of a diva :)